# Rows that float up

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using Angular to create a list of checkboxes that define whether some data is visible.

[image]

```
  $scope.data = [
  {name: "Data1", shown: true},
  {name: "Data2", shown: true},
  {name: "Data3", shown: true},
  {name: "Data4", shown: true},
  {name: "Data5", shown: true},
  {name: "Data6", shown: true}
  ];
```

This data is shown on a topbar, which has a limited height, thus not being able to fit the whole array of data.

```
<div class="contentBar">
  <div class="content" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="item.shown">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is: in case there are more than 4 visible instances of data, the last two should be put in another vertical row, on the right side of this row.

Here's a small demo plunker with this case.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vVysWYR5FLzIBh8zP8th?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Flexbox:

```
.contentBar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove height from `.contentBar` div , because you applied static height and data comes dynamically. Please changes below changes in your style.css

```
.contentBar{
   margin-top: 1em;
   background-color: black;
   width: 30em;
 }

.content {
   color: red !important;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Cheers dude.

Comment: This actually answers the question.

Comment: This is not what I meant in my question. The bar is required to have a fixed height and the content should wrap around it. It's my bad however, as I wasn't clear enough. The flexbox solution solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way how to achieve this is to use a flex box. **Please, see the updated [pluncker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0YssLHnF95VV1zJ0ZUE?p=preview)**.

The key are the last 3 CSS rules which were added to the contentBar:

```
.contentBar{
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  width: 30em;
  height: 5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

A very good guide to flex box can be found on the [CSS tricks site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).